# Why are some blocks not finding operations?

Tags: operation

"http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/BL8uS3sAr7UgtNryr4oyY9dJv4Nbds36UzvWbY6HRLvG1EiwoLA/operations"
"http://localhost:8732/chains/main/blocks/BLFFLhrVqdTw1HCagqKBbuAoSFQ8dZwyJgWqNCWgFvisbr8h8ff/operations"

Why is the second one not returning results?
rpc interface name: GET ..//operations

I suspect that the block before it was too long can not find the data with this interface.

Is there any other interface to query all transactions in a block?

Comment: What mode are you using? Full or rolling?

Comment: use default,full mode

Answer (score 1):

Your node seems to be running in either full mode or rolling mode. Our public node is running in full mode with a [snapshot](https://teznode.letzbake.com/chains/main/checkpoint) taken at level 532481 and it also does not find the [block](https://teznode.letzbake.com/chains/main/blocks/BLFFLhrVqdTw1HCagqKBbuAoSFQ8dZwyJgWqNCWgFvisbr8h8ff).

Block explorers need to run an archival node to provide their service. The block in question is found by [TzScan](https://tzscan.io/BLFFLhrVqdTw1HCagqKBbuAoSFQ8dZwyJgWqNCWgFvisbr8h8ff?default=endorsement) and you can see that it was baked at level 51856 - well before the checkpoint of our node.

To answer your second question: you need to either run a node in archival mode, use a block explorer or query an API like the one from [TzScan](https://tzscan.io/api).

Comment: Is the archival mode better than full mode?
Need to resynchronize?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you only need the node for baking or posting transactions, then running it in full mode is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you need to regularly query your node for data that goes back in time more than 5 cycles, then yes, you  would need running it in archive mode (if you have sufficient disk space).

Comment: “BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs”,
I can't find the data for this block.level is 583183,I checked the checkpoint of the node is 565249.Why can't I find it after the checkpoint?Node synchronization is also normal (data yesterday).

Comment: This is the inquiry yesterday.
Command:”tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/header”
result:
{
"protocol": "Pt24m4xiPbLDhVgVfABUjirbmda3yohdN82Sp9FeuAXJ4eV9otd",
  "chain_id": "NetXdQprcVkpaWU",
  "hash": "BKuTCRSUMSmGnQZRwwspDHNZBwkPW1S1GzfSkcyUC8XxXsEhoNw",
  "level": 585257, "proto": 4,
  "predecessor": "BLzvArdaSwFWaoiA8aqe3BRixELhwW3DyRWCRAgmb1Akpt4s6hk",
  "timestamp": "2019-08-29T12:28:06Z", "validation_pass": 4,
…
}

Comment: Command:”tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/checkpoint”
Result:
{ "block":
    { "level": 565249, "proto": 4,
      "predecessor": "BLS67xXrggsaaRY4K7KgnAeRgSY4AYGAJT7DKTeGBV4pLaAX1AT",
      "timestamp": "2019-08-15T04:37:30Z", "validation_pass": 4,
      "operations_hash":
        "LLoasv9zijFfMdv39fgP2rCbdAgtJXDWdmScaVjvmmvYfSHpZeVMt",
      "fitness": [ "00", "00000000010fee61" ],
      "context": "CoWAofm8nFFWM2kKCKf9FsrH5nTVE3ddiWJfwrU93hiP3JuiSB46",
      "protocol_data":...
        },
  "save_point": 565249, "caboose": 0, "history_mode": "full" }

Comment: You query the node for the tip (head) of the chain. These are the commands you are looking for:

Comment: tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs

Comment: tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/BMGi65PWTKoUbcs5hVm83LciAznJSQsKTrRLZ7HiLBNnoxgsJAs/header

Comment: These also have no data.Return "Did not find service ....".

Comment: Sorry, the comments section is not a chat function. Please open a new question, if you need further help.